# Prompt user for app feedback

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying to get an app review prompt to appear when they have opened my app for the 5th time but I don't seem to be having any luck. I've tried using the code on this site but it doesn't work for me. Are there any other ones available that anyone knows of?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2013/07/25/prompting-for-feedback-within-your-windows-phone-or-windows-8-app-game.aspx

```
    async protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
        #endif

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            // Set the default language
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

        int started = 0;
        if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("started"))
        {
            started = (int)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["started"];
        }

        started++;
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["started"] = started;

        if (started == 3)
        {
            var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Thank you for using this app?", "Please review my app");
            bool? reviewresult = null;
            md.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("OK", new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommandInvokedHandler((cmd) => reviewresult = true)));
            md.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Cancel", new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommandInvokedHandler((cmd) => reviewresult = false)));
            await md.ShowAsync();
            if (reviewresult == true)
            {
                string familyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN={0}", familyName)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Linking to an example of code doesn't actually show us what your implementation looks like - your question lacks any sort of context. Please edit.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like your culprit is `if (started == 10)`. Try changing that to 5?

Comment: Have you walked through with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling it before the app is initialized to the point where it can start the MessageDialog.

If you look at the article you're copying from you'll see that it says to put the new code at the bottom of the OnLaunched method after the call to Window.Current.Activate(), not at the beginning of the OnLaunched method.

If you do that then the dialog works as desired.

Comment: No, that's basically correct and it worked for me when I followed the tutorial. In what way is it not working for you? Have you walked through in the debugger? Where does it fail? Is the MessageDialog call being reached?